# How to pass a database query from a Model to a Controller in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Model file `product.js` which does this:

```
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

module.exports.rsProducts = function () { // update1: removed params req,res,next

        global.MYDB.connect(function (error) { // MYDB is a mssql-server database setup in app.js as a global variable
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            global.MYDB.request().query('SELECT Top(10) * FROM [dbo].[Product]', function (err, result) {

console.log(result); // this works and i see the database recordset in the console
return(result); // this does not seem to do anything (see below)

            });

        });
```

I have a controller file called `index.js` which calls the Model like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const Offer = require('../models/product');

Offer.rsProducts(); // the console.log(result) line in the model file logs the recordset to the console

console.log(Offer.rsProducts()); // this log does not log anything which means no result is being returned from the model file to this controller
```

My question is why does the `return(result)` line in the `product.js` Model not return anything to my Controller? Ultimately I want the Controller to render a view file like this:

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { pagetitle: 'Product Name', data: Offer.rsProducts() });
});`

The above never works because nothing is coming back from `Offers.rsProduct()`.

**UPDATE 1**
I need an answer that is scalable so that the Controller can call as many database functions, from as many models, as it needs to. The homepage of the website needs database data from about 4 different models. Really, the end result (I imagine in my head) is that the Controller would do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var router =  require('express').Router();
const Offer = require('../models/product');
const Story = require('../models/story');
const QandA = require('../models/qanda');
const Job =   require('../models/job');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { 
  pageTitle: 'Homepage', 
  offerData: Offer.rsProducts(), //calls Offer's rsProducts function to get the data
  storyData: Story.rsStories(), // calls Story's rsStories function to get the data
  qandaData: QandA.rsQandAs(), // calls QandA's rsQandAs function to get the data
  jobData:   Job.rsJobs() // calls Job's rsJobs function to get the data
});
});
```

Comment: I think you're miss-interpreting the point of a model. A model should tell your database how your data is structured. Secondly, you're not actually returning anything from rsProduct.

Comment: No expect here but you're not setting `Offer.rsProduct()` to anything so `return` has nowhere to return to.  I'm not sure but `return` in JavaScript may not be the best word to use...it's a reserved word.  Try `const result = Offer.rsProduct(); console.log(result)`

Comment: @denikov how does javascript return data back to the calling file without using the `return` function?

Comment: You’re right, I misread that. I thought return was one of your callback parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Too many things need to be explained there.

As you can see, all of 'I/O' functions (like, connect to database, query to db...) have a parameter like `function (err, result) {...` (`function (error)`...), and as your question "Why they not return the result directly instead of wrap it into a function?".

With Javascript, the function is a `Callback` function, JS does not work like a "normal" program language.

A hotfix for your case, I don't know why you define `rsProduct` function with `req, res, next` as parameters, but it is good for my way - Make  `rsProduct` become a "[Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)" function:

```
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

module.exports.rsProduct = function (req, res, next) {

  global.MYDB.connect(function (error) { // MYDB is a mssql-server database setup in app.js as a global variable
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return next(error); // call next with a error to stop flow and throw a error to express app
    }

    global.MYDB.request().query('SELECT Top(1) * FROM [dbo].[Prodcut]', function (err, result) {

      console.log(result); // this works and i see the database recordset in the console

      // !!! Assign the result to a new field of req object
      req.products = result; // maybe what you need is req.products = result.recordset;

      next(); // continue to your function to render view

    });

  })
}
```

then in your router,

```
var router = require('express').Router();
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const Offer = require('../models/product');

// Offer.rsProduct(); // the console.log(result) line in the model file logs the recordset to the console

// console.log(Offer.rsProduct()); // this log does not log anything which means no result is being returned from the model file to this controller

router.get('/', Offer.rsProduct, function (req, res, next) { //  Offer.rsProduct instead of  Offer.rsProduct()
  res.render('index', { pagetitle: 'Product Name', data: req.products }); // get back products list
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite going to work. I have updated my question `Update 1` so you may get a better idea of how I thought this would work. Or else I am stuck on how to get data out of a database for the homepage.